# how do i make a scanner variable become an array?

Tags: java, arrays

How would I possibly do this? I'm trying to do this but it says the param is string and it's requires `string[]`

here is my code  :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Launch {

    public static String[] josh = {
        "Josh", "mcMc", "16", "grade 11"
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.print("Please enter the first name of the person you would love to know about : ");
        String hisName = sc.next();
        printSomeInfoAbout(hisName);
    }

    public static void printSomeInfoAbout(String[] name) {

        System.out.println("My name is " + name[0] + " " + name[1] + ". I am " + name[2] + " " +
            "Years old and I am currently in " +
            name[3] + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously dude, you can not make a scanner variable to an array.

Comment: it's not an array, i was just trying to make it so the user input it accesses and outputs data from the array, not become an array itself

Comment: You are passing `hisName` - a `String` to `printSomeInfoAbout` which requires `String Array` - obviously it would say `param is String and it requires String[]`

Comment: It seems like you have set of person's info. And asking name string of the person and in return you print that person's infomation which stored.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
String[] hisName=new String[4]; 
for(int i=0;i<hisName.length;i++){
    hisName[i]=sc.nextLine();
}
printSomeInfoAbout(hisName);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will get what you are looking for:

```
public class Launch {
      public static String[] josh = {
            "Josh", "mcMc", "16", "grade 11"
        };
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
            System.out.print("Please enter the first name of the person you would love to know about : ");
            String hisName = sc.next();
            printSomeInfoAbout(hisName);
        }

        public static void printSomeInfoAbout(String name) {
            if(name.equals(josh[0])){
                System.out.println("My name is " + josh[0] + " " + josh[1] + ". I am " + josh[2] + " " +
                "Years old and I am currently in " +
                josh[3] + ".");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: @Boolena Then you should have asked the question correctly. Your Question Title nowhere comes close to the answer you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

If by first name you mean that the user will input "josh", then implement the `printSomeInfoAbout()` method as below.

```
public static void printSomeInfoAbout(String name){
    if(name.equals(josh[0])){
        System.out.println("My name is " + josh[0] + " " + josh[1] + ". I am " + josh[2] + " " +
        "Years old and I am currently in " +
        josh[3] + ".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Launch {

    public static String[] josh = {
        "Josh", "mcMc", "16", "grade 11"
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.print("Please enter the first name of the person you would love to know about : ");
        String hisName = sc.next();
        if(josh[0].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(hisName)){
             printSomeInfoAbout(josh);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Sorry unable to find search Name");
        }

    }

    public static void printSomeInfoAbout(String[] name) {

        System.out.println("My name is " + name[0] + " " + name[1] + ". I am " + name[2] + " " +
            "Years old and I am currently in " +
            name[3] + ".");
    }
}
```